# When my question is "ON HOLD", can the question be seen on the main page?

Tags: support

Are questions that are put ***ON HOLD*** visible in the main forum of questions?

Comment: Putting a question "on hold" does not effect its visibility on the front page, so far as I know. Of course, question closure sometimes also corresponds with downvotes, and if your question collects enough of those to have a net negative score (below some threshold), it will be hidden from the front page. But, hidden or not, "on hold" questions can't be answered, so I suppose it doesn't matter that much?

Answer (score 2):

Being put "On Hold" leaves the question in the list at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions so people will be able to find it.

There is an algorithm that pushes questions off the [main page](https://english.stackexchange.com/) so that "better" questions get more viewing time. If a question is "On Hold", it will likely be pushed of the front page, but it is still viewable from the questions page and it is still searchable.

Comment: it may encourage it to move off more quickly, but simply being placed on hold does not immediately force your question off the front page; indeed, there are many questions here on meta complaining about how many closed questions ("closed" = the old name for "on hold") are on the front page.